# Is there away to stop flex-flow: column wrap: after hitting 4 columns?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of names and i want the names to fill one column and if the names fill the first column (which is the height of the browser) i want the over flow to start filling the second then third etc. Im using flex-flow: column wrap; to achieve this. The tricky part is how do i stop at 4 columns?

I tried column-count: 4; and giving the wrapper a width and none of that works

```
html 
<div class="wrapper">
    <div *ngFor="let foo of FooBar"></div
</div>
.wrapper{
    column-count: 4;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: calc(100vh - 250px);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: :nth-child(4n) {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

Comment: what do you want to happen if there are more than 4 columns? what does your html look like?

Comment: Columns count has nothing to do with flexbox

Comment: What is supposed to happen if there are more names than would fill 4 columns

Comment: If the 4th column fills up the height of the wrapper will grow, thats how they want it to work :\

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="foo" *ngFor="let foo of FooBar"></div
</div>
.wrapper{
    column-count: 4;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: calc(100vh - 250px);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.foo {
  max-width: 25%;
}
```